# Request old data from pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-pinpoint

I have been using kinesis firehose to move pinpoint data to s3 from jan 2019 ,since its 2019 the folder which is getting written is 'myproj-2019' but I need 2018 data too. Is there any way to fetch old data by configuring firehose stream or do we need to make a request to aws.

Comment: It does not quite sounds to fit the concept of event streams. Maybe you can reach the old data of pinpoint via its API and move to S3 e.g. with a Lambda function?

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought too but in the doc they mentioned pinpoint data will get expired within 90 days we can retain it only if it gets moved to Kinesis or S3 within the period, so that's the problem.

Comment: I had this issue already and so far there is no solution to retrieve and the best option is to setup Kinesis Data Firehose from start to avoid any data loss. Refer to this question for detail response from AWS Support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74049983/how-to-retrieve-old-events-from-aws-pinpoint/74119347#74119347