# How to retrieve old events from AWS Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, aws-pinpoint

I'm trying to retrieve 1-week old events from AWS pinpoint. But I cannot find any documentation for how to retrieve old data. The AWS documentation doesn't help at all.

Can someone please advise how can I retrieve 1 week old Pinpoint events and send to Kinesis Data Stream.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**This is for anyone reading in the future**

There is no answer to retrieve old events as I'm writing this on 19th of Oct 2022, hope a solution will be found in the future :)

Below is the response received from AWS Support:

Unfortunately there is no way to fetch or retrieve events if Kinesis stream is not enabled for Pinpoint as Pinpoint doesn't have logging enabled for Cloudwatch logs. Pinpoint events can only be streamed using Kinesis stream for more information please refer [1].

However, Pinpoint utilizes SES service to send mails and SES activity/event data can be seen from Cloudwatch metrics[2] . Moving forward using internal tools I have tried to check the CW metrics data for your account and CW metrics for the same can be seen from link[3]. Please note that metrics which are shown are not only of Pinpoint it is the number of mail events trigerred including Pinpoint and others if any.

I hope above information would prove helpful to you and Aplogies in case above information will not suffice your requirements. Please feel free to get back to us if you need further clarification or if you have any query, I’ll be happy to assist you.

// When I have asked if we can utilise any sort of script to back date. Below is the answer of it:

I understand that you need event data for the week when Kinsesis was not configured and the event data is critical for your use case However to answer your query we can not pull events for the back date using any script/code/lamda, the only way is to use Kinesis stream as those events are streamed live and not stored anywhere in customer environment, unless it is streamed to any destination via. Kinesis(which you have already configured now), as keeping your need and sentiments in consideration I reached out to internal team as well and requested if they can help in any way. However below is the response I received from them:

- We can not retrieve the event data from our end. Only option is to use event streaming to collect event data.

Apologies I am not able to help you in this issue.

I hope you will understand my limitations in this situation and if there is anything further you wish for me to clarify or if you have any further questions, it would only be my pleasure to answer them and help guide you.